# ZF2 + Duplicate Form Validation on composite key

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, db2, duplicates, zend-form2

I have a Form having primary key on two fields (gid, bid). I need to add validation to block duplicate entries into database.

I have checked with ZF2 Solution for this . http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.db.html#excluding-records . While this approach of handling composite keys is not look the ideal way, But still I am trying it because it look like only buil-in way. Now it require me to provide second field's value (value option in exclude), which is again a problem. As I am trying it

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
     'name'     => 'gid',
     'required' => true,
     'validators' => array(
         array(
                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                'options' => array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        'isEmpty' => 'required'
                    ),
                 ),
         ),
         array (
            'name' => 'Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists',
            'options' => array (
                'table' => 'gtable',
                'field' => 'gid',
                'adapter' => $this->dbAdapter,
                'messages' => array(
                    \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'The specified key already exists in database' 
                ),
                'exclude' => array(
                    'field' => 'bid',
                    'value' => [?],
                ),
            )
        ),
     )
 ));
```

How do I get this value, As Form is absolute separate Class/File than controller where I have the submitted form values. Is some better architecture solution of this problem exists  Or Some hack to pass submitted field value to Form Class is only solution ?

Note : I am not in favor of Build My Validation Plugin for this task as short time is constraint for functionality.

Comment: where comes the ``bid`` value from?

Comment: @ins0, Actually that is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all the job in your form. To achieve that, you could define your forms as **factories** in your module **Module.php**.

**Module.php**

```
use MyNamespace\MyForm;

//NOTE THAT THE SERVICE MANAGER IS INJECTED. YOUR FORM COULD RECEIVE IT THROUGH THE CONSTRUCTOR
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'my_form' => function( $sm ) {
                $form = new MyForm( $sm );

                return $form;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

When you want to use the form is as easy as use this code in your controller:

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function createAction() {
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get( 'my_form' ) );
        (...)
    }
}
```

And your **MyForm.php**

```
use Zend\Form\Form;

class MyForm extends Form
{
    public $serviceManager, $request, $postData;

    public function __construct( $serviceManager ) {
        parent::__construct( null );

        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
        $this->request = $serviceManager->get( 'Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRequest();
        $this->postData = get_object_vars( $this->request->getPost() );
    }
}
```

This way you can get advantage of the **Service Manager** within your form. And the public `postData`, where you'll find the `bid` value you're looking for to build your `NoRecordExists` filter.

Comment: Solution works & validatation work fine. Just one problem only one field show errors but that is not easy to fix I assume.

Comment: The `exclude` option is a mixed var. It means that can be an array with `field` and `value` keys or a string like `gid = [?] AND bid = [?]`. You could try it this way, and add this `exclude` setting to validators of both inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the parameters to the getInputFilter, like this :

```
getInputFilter($gid, $bid)
```

And then on the controller, when you set the filter you pass the 2 parameters, and then just check as $form->isValid(); ...

**Alternative try this:**

```
                array(
                    'name' => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
                    'options' => array(
                        'table' => 'gtable',
                        'field' => 'gid',
                        'adapter' => $this->dbAdapter,
                    ),
                ),
```

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, But no validation performed, And database throw duplicate error every times. I checked through bjyprofile and found correct query executed, But no validation error comes.

Comment: can you post the code of how you setFilter on the controller?

Comment: `$postData = $request->getPost();$form->setInputFilter($form->getInputFilter($postData['bid']));`

Comment: Ok so try to use a different name on your method call it getInputFilterCustom($bid, ...); because now you are overriding the current getInputFilter on form, and this always bring unwanted behaviours.

Comment: But all other validations is just work fine. I just have one change from tutorial that I place inputfilter into Form itself instead of Model.

Comment: Usually the getinputfilter goes in a separated class, that why we set it using setInputFilter, otherwise it would be done automatically without having to call setInputFilter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure on your use case. If you were to add a database entry the primary keys for that table would not be known until you insert anyway - If you have foreign key constraints you could handle the exception from the database.

> I am not in favor of Build My Validation Plugin for this task

The validator is also not designed to validate multiple fields as they are attached to a form element on a 1-1 basis. You will therefore need to create your own.

The below example has **NOT** been tested, so take it as an example of the approach rather than working code.

The key bit is the `isValid` method.

```
namespace MyModule\Validator\Db;

use Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists;

class CompositeNoRecordExists extends NoRecordExists
{
    protected $field2;

    protected $field2Value;

    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);

        if (array_key_exists('field2', $options)) {

            $this->setField2($options['field2']);
        } else {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException('Missing field2 option!');
        }
    }

    protected function setField2Value(array $context)
    {
        if (! isset($context[$this->field2])) {

            throw new \BadMethodCallException('Unable to find value for field 2');
        }
        $this->field2Value = $context[$this->field2];
    }

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        // The isValid() method is actually given a 2nd argument called $context
        // Which is injected by the inputFilter, via the input and into the validator chain
        // $context contains all of RAW form element values, keyed by thier element name.

        // Unfortunately due to the ValidatorInterface you are unable to add this to the method
        // signature. So you will need to be 'creative':

        $args = func_get_args();

        if (isset($args[1]) && is_array($args[1])) {

            $this->setField2Value($args[1]);

        } else {
            throw new \BadMethodCallException('Missing validator context');
        } 

        return parent::isValid($value);
    }


    public function getSelect()
    {
        $select = parent::getSelect();

        $select->where->equalTo($this->field2, $this->field2Value);

        return $select;
    }

}
```

Then all you would need to do is update the validator config, adding the `field2` field name.

```
array (
    'name' => 'MyModule\Validator\Db\CompositeNoRecordExists',
    'options' => array (
        'table'    => 'gtable',
        'field'    => 'gid',
        'field2'   => 'bid',
        'adapter'  => $this->dbAdapter,
        'messages' => array(
            \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'The specified key already exists in database' 
        ),
    )
),
```